# meaning of $X'=AX$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

i have been trying to learn differential equations and I saw various types and methods to solve those types of equations.

My question is that $X'=AX$ represents linear DE but I am just seeing linear transformation when I am seeing $AX$. What does this represent ?

Comment: $A$ is a matrix and $X$ is vector, where do you see a linear transformation  ?

Comment: Informally, the equation $X' = AX$ says that the flow of the solutions at the point $X$ is tangent to the image of the point $X$ under the transformation $A$.

Comment: It *is* just a linear transformation. But it's one on a space of *functions*, not on $\mathbb{R}^n$, so the elements of $A$ are functions instead of numbers. The vector $X'$ of functions is a linear transformation $A$ of $X$. Given $A$, find the $X$ that satisfy this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to bring up an example to show you the point. Let a nonhomogeneeous system below: 
$$
 \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{dx}{dt}=-2x+5y+e^t-2t \\\\\\\\
            \frac{dy}{dt}=4x-3y+10t
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
 It can be written as : $$\frac{d\mathbf{X}}{dt}=\begin{pmatrix}
  -2 & 5\\
  4 & -3 \end{pmatrix}\mathbf{X}+\begin{pmatrix}
  e^t-2t\\
  10t \end{pmatrix}$$

Or $$\mathbf{X}'=\begin{pmatrix}
  -2 & 5\\
  4 & -3 \end{pmatrix}\mathbf{X}+\begin{pmatrix}
  e^t-2t\\
  10t \end{pmatrix}$$ where in $\mathbf{X}=\begin{pmatrix}
  x(t)\\
  y(t) \end{pmatrix}$ and $A$ for example is $A=\begin{pmatrix}
  -2 & 5\\
  4 & -3 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: what does $\frac { dx }{ dt } =-2x+5y+{ \e  }^{ t }-2t$ represent...? Can u please put some example that results in this type of equations ?

Comment: @rafiki: If you found out what is X and what is A, so for the origin of such these systems, you can search the web for application. For example in Electrical Networks.

Comment: $\ddot\smile\quad {}{}{}{}{}$